# Is there a way to modify module content after compilation in webpack5 plugin?

Tags: webpack-5, webpack-plugin

webpack5 plugin: i want to modify module content after compilation. modification of dependencies is not involved. my modifications need to be specified in the file and modified via the AST . how can i do  ?

i have tried `module._source._value = newModuleContent`, but it failed